# Change items in list of list into assigned value and use them for calculations

Tags: python, list, sum, variable-assignment

I'm trying to calculate the value of all lists in a Python list of lists (fixed_uncertainty2).

First, I need to convert each item of the sublist to a value assigned by the dictionary item_var (e.g. convert 'F' into 2). Then I want to compute the sum (and then either store it in a variable or print it). I need to do this for each sublist. So for the first sublist below, it would be converted to [2, 1, -2, -1, 2, 1], so its sum (saved as comb_value) = 3.

With the code below, I can only manage to do this for the first sub list, but then it won't convert the values in the other sublists to numbers. Does anyone know where the bug is?

```
i = 0
j = 0
comb = []
item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}
fixed_uncertainty2 = [['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c']]
while j in range(len(fixed_uncertainty2)):
    comb = fixed_uncertainty2[j]
    while i in range(len(comb)):
        for item in comb:
            comb[i] = item_var[item]
            i += 1
        comb_value = sum(comb)
```

Comment: line number 6, it mutst be `for j ...` i think

Comment: IIUC: `[sum(map(lambda x: item_var[x],  i)) for i in fixed_uncertainty2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused the usage of the keyword `while` and the keyword `for`.

Either way moving `i = 0` one line on top of the second while-loop and adding `j += 1` at the end will make your code work. But the pythonic way to do would have been to use built-in functions like that:

```
item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}
fixed_uncertainty2 = [['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c']]

for sublist in fixed_uncertainty2:
    comb_value = sum(map(lambda x: item_var[x], sublist))
    print(comb_value)
```

Trying checking about for-loops and built-in functions :

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}

fixed_uncertainty2 = [["F", "f", "C", "c", "F", "f"],
                      ["F", "f", "C", "c", "F", "F"],
                      ["F", "f", "C", "c", "f", "F"],
                      ["F", "f", "C", "c", "f", "f"],
                      ["F", "f", "C", "c", "C", "c"]]

comb = sum([item_var[i] for j in fixed_uncertainty2 for i in j])

print(comb)
```

Output:

```
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Bug is in the first while! you are not adding to "**j**" after each round is completed!

```
comb = []
item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}
fixed_uncertainty2 = [['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c']]
while j in range(len(fixed_uncertainty2)):
    comb = fixed_uncertainty2[j]
    while i in range(len(comb)):
        for item in comb:
            comb[i] = item_var[item]
            i += 1
        comb_value = sum(comb)
    j+=1
```

BTW, why don't you use `for` instead? just to avoid these little bugs and a cleaner code:

```
comb = []
item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}
fixed_uncertainty2 = [['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c']]
for j in range(len(fixed_uncertainty2)):
    comb = fixed_uncertainty2[j]
    for i in range(len(comb)):
        for item in comb:
            comb[i] = item_var[item]
        comb_value = sum(comb)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item_var = {"F": 2, "f": 1, "C": -2, "c": -1}
fixed_uncertainty2 = [
    ["F", "f", "C", "c", "F", "f"],
    ["F", "f", "C", "c", "F", "F"],
    ["F", "f", "C", "c", "f", "F"],
    ["F", "f", "C", "c", "f", "f"],
    ["F", "f", "C", "c", "C", "c"],
]

for sub_list in fixed_uncertainty2:
    for index, item in enumerate(sub_list[:]):
        sub_list[index] = item_var.get(item, item)
```

At this point `fixed_uncertainty2` has changed to:

```
[
    [2, 1, -2, -1, 2, 1],
    [2, 1, -2, -1, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, -2, -1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, -2, -1, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, -2, -1, -2, -1],
]
```

Now to calculate the sum of every sublist separately:

```
sum_of_sub_lists = [sum(sub_list) for sub_list in fixed_uncertainty2]
```

which will give you the final output as:

```
[3, 4, 3, 2, -3]
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem with the other solutions is that they ultimately do 30 dictionary lookups, as well as one or more loops, at the Python level.  What if we could potentially push all these dictionary lookups, and loop(s) down to the '**C**' level:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}

fixed_uncertainty = [
    ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'f'],
    ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'F'],
    ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'F'],
    ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'f'],
    ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c'],
]

comb = sum(itemgetter(*chain(*fixed_uncertainty))(item_var))

print(comb)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
9
%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comb = []
item_var = {'F': 2, 'f': 1, 'C': -2, 'c': -1}
fixed_uncertainty2 = [['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'F', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'F'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'f', 'f'], ['F', 'f', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c']]
sub_sums = []
for sublist in fixed_uncertainty2:
    values = [item_var[k] for k in sublist]
    sub_sums.append(sum(values))
```

Here you have `sub_sums` with

```
[3, 4, 3, 2, -3]
```

And the overall sum would be `sum()` of the `sub_sums`